# Struggling with Raspbian Bluetooth communication

Tags: raspbian, boot, serial, bluetooth

I'm trying to perform communication between my Raspberry with a slave Bluetooth module and my laptop. The goal is to get a boot output message of my Raspberry, but that's not working as expected.

The pairing with my laptop works as expected, but when I boot my Raspberry, I don't get the boot log, I only get this message when the raspberry reboot:

> "Uncompressing Linux... done, booting the kernel"

From a tutorial, it says that you must configure `/boot/cmdline.txt` with this:

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyAMA0,9600 kgdboc=ttyAMA0,9600
console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline
rootwait
```

which I did.

Then modify `/etc/inittab` too:

```
T0:23:respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyAMA0 9600 vt100
```

After that it says that you must pair the Bluetooth with a third device, what I did with my laptop with:

```
> screen /dev/tty.RedFireFly-SPP 960
```

and then I reboot my Raspberry (`sudo reboot`). But the only output I get from screen is:

> Uncompressing Linux... done, booting the kernel.

The expected result should be the bootlog of Raspberry.

So I know the pairing and the serial communication are working because I get some output. However, I never get the boot log, and what I type in screen is never sent to the RPi. I really don't understand why this is not working and I can't find anywhere on website how to make it work properly. By the way my RPi OS is on Jessie Lite.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**edit:** I finally switched to Wheezy and it worked without performing any configuration.

**edit 2:** Ok I figured out, my bluetooth module was actually configured at 115200 bauds, so changing the baud at 115200 and not 9600 in my cmdline did the trick... (I was sure my bt was configured at 9600. But I changed the baud rate in another project and I totally forget it was still at 115200 -_-.)